# Primefaces - Tabs not visible

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using Liferay 6.2 on a JBoss 7.1.1. I created a primefaces portlet and just want to display a TabView. This is the easiest scenario and even that isnt working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"  
      >
    <h:body>

<h3>Tab Test</h3>
    <p:tabView scrollable="true">
        <p:tab title="Tab 1">Tab 1 Content</p:tab>
        <p:tab title="Tab 2">Tab 2 Content</p:tab>
        <p:tab title="Tab 3">Tab 3 Content</p:tab>
        <p:tab title="Tab 4">Tab 4 Content</p:tab>   
    </p:tabView>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

In this image you can see how it looks like, no tabs are shown, just ugly links:

[image]

What is going wrong here? I looked in the WEB-INF/lib folder, there is a primefaces.jar file, maybe I have to add a dependency in some way?
A `<p:button>` is correctly displayed as button, if this is helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably just need

```
<h:head>
</h:head>
```

above `<h:body>`. Primefaces uses this to include it's css and js.