# Primefaces tab closable="true" no crosses are visible

Tags: css, primefaces

This is my tabView component

```
<p:tabView id="toolbarTabSet" orientation="top" scrollable="true"
    activeIndex="#{toolbarBean.tabIndex}" styleClass="toolbar" onTabChange="startProgress();">
    <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{toolbarBean.processTabChange}"/>
```

And my tab component

```
<p:tab id="activeReportsTab"
    styleClass="toolbarTab"
    rendered="#{toolbarBean.activeReportsRendered}"
    title="#{msg['WEB_TOOLBAR_BTN_REPORTS']}" closable="true">
```

I am migrating from old Icefaces to the newest Primefaces 5.3.5 with JSF 2.2.8 on Tomcat 7.
I have inserted also

```
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
</h:body>
```

I see only ugly links without tabs and crosses. Something like
[Primefaces - Tabs not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24991364/primefaces-tabs-not-visible)

Comment: I do not have at the beginning of file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"  
      >

Comment: Are the CSS and js files included in the resulting html?

Comment: I have linked JS but not sure, if CSS is linked properly.

Comment: You'll get something "ugly" if the CSS is not there.  You should see something like `theme.css.xhtml` in the resulting html source.

Comment: I cannot use a primefaces theme. I have to use own CSS classes, just developed or adopt them. There is no theme in my html inspector in Mozilla.

Comment: I do not see also arrows to expand primefaces tree component.

Comment: So you effectively are saying you do not use any primefaces theme and it looks bad now. Then the only thing to do is fix your custom css. This has nothing to do with primefaces, javascript or jsf-2.2 (or jsf in general)

Comment: @Kukeltje Yes, you are right. It is a CSS issue.